# How to set / configure the max size of a solr index file?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, search-engine, lucene

How do I configure the max size of a Solr Index file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the discussion - [Control Segment Size](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Control-segment-size-td497293.html) on the Solr User mailing list, there, unfortunately, is not any way to control the max size of a Solr index file (also known as a segment).

In order for the answer to contain the actual details, here are the details from the thread:

You want to set: maxMergeDocs. "While merging segments, Lucene will ensure that no segment with more than maxMergeDocs is created."

There is no way to limit an individual file to a specific size.

An individual segment will not contain more than maxMergeDocs number of 
documents. But the size of the segment may still vary because some documents 
may have more unique tokens than others.

What you saw originally must have been a segment merge which is normal and 
happens in the course of indexing. I don't think there's a way to avoid that 
other than to have a ridiculously high mergeFactor (which will affect search 
performance).

Comment: that post is from 2009. i was hoping things might have changed since then :)

Comment: Sorry, there has not been any change since then. The algorithms that Solr uses to manage the segments has been improved since then, so perhaps you should look into the default TieredMergePolicy that is the default.

Comment: Thanks Paige. Do you know if there is a way to tell Solr to store the entire index as one file, instead of segments?

Comment: @SaqibAli: you can trigger a forceMerge(1) or deprecated optimize to merge all segments, but an update still creates new segments.

Answer (score 1):

As of solr 6, max size of segment can be set now.
Note that `maxMergeDocs` is **deprecated**.

The default `mergePolicyFactory` is `TieredMergePolicyFactory`. It has a property `MaxMergedSegmentMB` which controls the segment size. From [javadocs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0//core/org/apache/lucene/index/TieredMergePolicy.html):

> If a merge will produce a segment that's larger than
>   setMaxMergedSegmentMB(double), then the policy will merge fewer
>   segments (down to 1 at once, if that one has deletions) to keep the
>   segment size under budget.

For e.g. to set max segment size to 3000 MB:

```
<mergePolicyFactory class="solr.TieredMergePolicyFactory">
    <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">10</int>
    <int name="segmentsPerTier">10</int>
    <int name="maxMergedSegmentMB">3000</int>
</mergePolicyFactory>
```